# How to apply right filter to get list of variables to an jinga variable with correct indentation

Tags: ansible, devops, aws-devops

I have an template in ansible role that uses variable and the variables are defined in vars.yaml

the template looks like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    {{ vm_guest_interface }}:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [{{ vm_static_ip }}]
      nameservers:
           addresses: [{{ vm_dns_servers }}]
      routes: 
        {{ vm_routes }}
```

the variable for vm_routes are passed as below in vars.yaml

```
vm_routes: 
  - to: 0.0.0.0/0
    via: 192.168.0.1
  - to: 192.168.0.0/16
    via: 192.168.0.101
```

but after running the playbook i am getting the values for variable without maintaining indentation. the output looks like below

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    {{ vm_guest_interface }}:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [{{ vm_static_ip }}]
      nameservers:
           addresses: [{{ vm_dns_servers }}]
      routes: 
        [{'to': '0.0.0.0/0', 'via': '192.168.0.1'}, {'to': '192.168.0.0/16', 'via': '192.168.0.101'}}
```

But i need the output to be correctly indented, the expected output is

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    {{ vm_guest_interface }}:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [{{ vm_static_ip }}]
      nameservers:
           addresses: [{{ vm_dns_servers }}]
      routes: 
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
        - to: 192.168.0.0/16
          via: 192.168.0.101
```

Can anyone help me how to get the values for jinga variables in the correct format with proper indentation. Thanks in advance

I tried using jinga filters for templates such as "to_yaml" and "to_nice_yaml" , but left out with same indentation problem

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    {{ vm_guest_interface }}:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [{{ vm_static_ip }}]
      nameservers:
           addresses: [{{ vm_dns_servers }}]
      routes: 
        {{ vm_routes | to_yaml }}
```

output looks like

network:
version: 2
ethernets:
{{ vm_guest_interface }}:
dhcp4: no
addresses: [{{ vm_static_ip }}]
nameservers:
addresses: [{{ vm_dns_servers }}]
routes:
- {to: 0.0.0.0/0, via: 192.168.0.1}

- {to: 192.168.0.0/16, via: 192.168.0.101}

Answer (score 1):

Given the variables for testing

```yaml
    vm_guest_interface: eth0
    vm_static_ip:
      - 10.2.0.11
    vm_dns_servers:
      - 10.2.0.10
    vm_routes: 
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.0.1
      - to: 192.168.0.0/16
        via: 192.168.0.101
```

Use Jinja filter [indent](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) to indent the whole structure. Set also the indentation inside the structure by the function [to_nice_yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) when needed. For example, the template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          network:
            version: 2
            ethernets:
              {{ vm_guest_interface }}:
                dhcp4: no
                addresses:
                  {{ vm_static_ip|to_nice_yaml|indent(8) }}
                nameservers:
                  addresses:
                    {{ vm_dns_servers|to_nice_yaml|indent(10) }}
                routes: 
                  {{ vm_routes|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(8) }}
```

gives

```yaml
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        eth0:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses:
            - 10.2.0.11
  
          nameservers:
            addresses:
              - 10.2.0.10
  
          routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.0.1
            - to: 192.168.0.0/16
              via: 192.168.0.101
```

It's not possible to get rid of the new lines created by the function *to_nice_yaml*, I think.

---

See:

- Examples of [netplan](https://ansible-linux-postinstall.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-task-netplan.html)
- Template [netplan_conf.j2](https://ansible-linux-postinstall.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotation-templates.html#netplan-conf-j2)